# Как настроить эмулятор в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualbox, настройка, эмулятор

Всем, привет!

Настраиваю Andoid Studio на VirtualBox (windows7). Возникла проблема с эмулятором.

В БИОСе самого железа `virtualization technology` включен. В образе VirtualBox `Включить VT-x` стоит. При попытке установить HAXM (https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) выдает:

`VT support -- no, NX support - yes`

Что еще можно подкрутить, чтоб пользоваться эмулятором?

Спасибо.

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что вы установили виртуалку с виндой, на которую пытаетесь поставить эмулятор Android? Виртуалка в виртуалке? Но зачем? Почему не установить Android Studio в свою систему?

Comment: @metalurgus , был ряд технических ограничений. Тоже пришел к мнению, что Студию не стоит ставить на виртуалку. Остался чисто академический интерес.

Comment: Можете попробовать пользоваться сторонними эмкляторами, например Genymotion

Comment: При установке HAXM, самому этому модулю на винде я выставлял 1Гб, как рекомендуемое. Попробуйте дать больше озушки для виртуальной машины, так как HAXM жрёт много, ну и для этого модуля при установке дайте рекомендуемый объём, если до установки вообще доходит